# Swift, get data from [String: Any] type value

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I have a value like this;

```
["id1": {
name = "iphone 6s";
price = 330;
}, "id2": {
    name = iphone7s;
    price = 500;
}]
```

I dont know what the id's are. But I need to get the name and the price data from that data.

**EDIT:** Here is the getting value code;

```
database.child("SortedItems").child("byName").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
            return
        }
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with json, do you have a dictionary or a json message?

Comment: It’s a straightforward dictionary so what is the problem? Please show any code attempt you’ve made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data structure matches what you have quoted at the top, you should be able to cast your first line as:

```
guard let data = snapshot.value as? [String:[String:Any]]
```

If not, t would be helpful to see what the console looks like if you print `snapshot.value`

---

Then, the following from my previous answer *should* work:

```
let ids = data.keys //get just the ids/keys

//iterate through and print the name and price once they're cast to the correct types
data.forEach { (key,value) in
    if let name = value["name"] as? String, let price = value["price"] as? Int {
        print(name)
        print(price)
    }
}

//declare a model type that conforms to Codable
struct Phone : Codable {
    var name : String
    var price : Int
}

data.forEach { (key, value) in
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: [])
//decode the Phone model 
        let phoneModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(Phone.self, from: jsonData)
        print(phoneModel)
    } catch {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

You may also want to look at the Firebase docs, which give some more detail about getting your data, including converting to custom objects: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Hey, I updated the question. Added the getting data function. I edited your code with changing data with value. And it throws me an error says value of type any has no subscripts on the line if let name = value["name"] as? String, let price = value["price"] as? Int {